# Fonts: Exporting from Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, fonts, pdf, export

How can I preserve font characteristics when exporting from InDesign? When I export from InDesign using settings such as these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

my text comes out very clunky on the generated pdf. The colors are different, the weight is different, etc. This is a comparison of the generated vs what I see in InDesign:

[image]

How can I preserve the fonts in the export?

Comment: You should supply some more info - does it happen with all fonts or specific one/s? That would probably mean a problem with the font itself, the file type etc.. My best guess is that in the save screen, under compatibility drop menu, choose acrobat 8/9.

Comment: InDesign has its own font renderer, which in general has a tendency to make text look slightly thinner than most other renderers. That's just a fact of using InDesign. There's nothing much you can do about it. It's like opening the same website in Safari and Firefox (on a Mac)—Firefox renders the exact same text much heavier than Safari.

Comment: You should make that in to an answer @JanusBahsJacquet  :)